# Meaning of "Schemas are changed infrequently, if at all"

Tags: meaning, sentence

As the question title implies, the following is a simple sentence written in plain English.

> - Schemas are changed infrequently, **if at all**.

Where *schema* is a special term used in Database Management System - DBMS implying *the overall logical structure of a database* or simply say *the overall design of a database*. A *database* can be thought of as a collection of well-structured, well-organized and **interrelated** tables that may contain a huge collection of **related** information in the form of rows (or records - an older term) and columns (or fields - an older term) in each of the tables.

The terms *row*, *column* and *table* in DBMS are especially designated by the terms *entity*, *attribute* and *entity class* or *entity set* respectively. An *entity class* in DBMS is also called *a relation* in **very special** contexts (for example, normalization).

The terms *record* and *field* were especially used before the advent of DBMSs.

---

The meaning of the main clause is obvious but I really don't get the meaning of the subordinate clause or if-clause. It appears that something is deliberately disguised in the *if-clause* for some specific reasons.

What does ***if at all*** mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"**if at all**" is an idiomatic phrase whose meaning tends to emphasize a restriction stated in the preceding clause. In this case, the statement is equivalent to:

> *Schemas are changed infrequently, if **schemas are changed** at all.*

In more explicit terms:

> *Schemas are changed infrequently, and it may often be the case that a schema is never changed.*

This idiom also can take the forms "if ever", "if anything", "if anybody/anyone", etc.

Comment: @Tiny that sentence doesn't make sense because "if at all" refers to quantity or frequency. A better example is "I rarely have tea in the morning, if at all".

Comment: @Tiny You could say "Have a cup of tea in the morning, if any".

Comment: I have a cup of tea in the morning, if ever.

Comment: In this context, the "if at all" is probably trying to reinforce that the goal or intention is that schemas not change at all and that at worst they'll change infrequently. (We'd need more context to be sure, but that's one way this construct is commonly used.)

Answer (score 11):

SUPPLEMENTAL:
Mark Beadles' answer is entirely correct. I add this only to clarify how the construction works and how you may extend it in the matter he suggests.

The basic structure is **A<sub>1</sub>, if not A<sub>2</sub>**, where A<sub>2</sub> is an adjective or adverb in the same scale as A<sub>1</sub>, but more extreme. For example:

- reddish, if not red
- most, if not all
- some, if not most
- sometimes, if not often

If A<sub>2</sub> is a negative, however, the double negative **not A<sub>2</sub>** looks odd or ungrammatical, and is rewritten as a positive

- few, if *not none ---> few, if any
- rarely, if *not never ---> rarely, if ever

Your example is one of these rewritten double negatives:

- infrequently, if *not not at all ---> infrequently, if at all

The sense in all these is “*I assert A<sub>1</sub>, but I will not go quite so far as to assert A<sub>2</sub>, although I hold it open as a possibility*”.

Answer (score 2):

It may make more sense if you reverse the order,

> If at all, schemas are changed infrequently.

Rephrasing even further:

> If they are ever changed at all, it is done infrequently.